# Use CGAAffineTransform to rotate a + symbol in the middle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to rotate a + to become an x, but it's not rotating via the center of the +. How can i get it to rotate via that point?

Comment: Where are you applying to transform to? (view/layer/CGContext/...?)

Comment: I'm applying it to a UILabel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggest just rotate the label :)

```
CGAffineTransform rotare = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45*M_PI/180.0f);
[plusLabel setTransform:rotare];
```

If the label is not rotating around the + center include the QuartzCore and rotate the [plusLabel layer]

```
CATransform3D rotate3D = CATransform3DMakeRotation(45*M_PI/180.0f, 0, 0, 1);
[[plusLabel layer] setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.4, 0.6)]; // The center of Plus in my case
[[plusLabel layer] setTransform:rotate3D];
```

Comment: That's the code i more or less already had. The problem is though that it doesn't rotate around the middle of the +, it's off center.

Comment: That's off center for me still, but I can fix that by messing with the numbers. The problem is, it's inside a UIView animation, so it jumps before rotating.

Comment: Identify the center of Plus in your layer and set the anchor point as I described. It should work. Remember that anchorPoint is a point between (0, 0) top left and (1, 1) button right